# ReactJS - Redirect in main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect to other page with search results after submitting form (search bar feature).

I will usually redirect with `return <Redirect to={'/search/' + this.state.value} />` in `render()`, but I can't now since I need to render entire site (search bar is in main component). 
I already tried `this.props.history.push('/search/' + this.state.value)` and `this.context.router.history.push('/search/' + this.state.value)` in place of comment but it doesn't work.

(Code simplified for clarity)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  BrowserRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Search from "./Search";
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  // react-autosuggest code

  search(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Redirect to '/search/' + this.state.value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <div className="header">
            <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.search}>
                {/* Autosuggest input which updates this.state.value */}
            </form>
          </div>

          <div className="main">
            <Route path="/search/:handle" component={Search} />
            {/* Other Routes */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Both `this.props.history` and `this.context.router.history` are undefined if I try to use them. `<Redirect />` (obviously) can't be rendered instead of `<BrowserRouter />`

Comment: What is the issue with `<Redirect />`?

Comment: I can't do something like `render() { return ( this.state.shouldSearch ? <Redirect to={"/search/" + this.state.value} /> : <BrowserRouter>{/* Site */}</BrowserRouter>); }` because site won't load, and when I try to use `search(e) { e.preventDefault(); return <Redirect to={"/search/" + this.state.value} /> }` it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Why you are adding condition in render. No need of conditional rendering here. Remove the condition just make it simple for BrowserRoutes only.

Comment: Yeah, I know - I just wanted to say that I can't do something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC to `App`, giving you access to [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) as a *prop*?

```js
class App extends Component {
  // ...
  search(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/search/${this.state.value}`)
  }
  // ....
}
export default withRouter(App)
```

Comment: Wrapping App in withRouter() gives "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>"

Comment: Just remove `BrowserRouter ` from the App, put it outside the App component. something like `render(<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>, document.body)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import [`Redirect`](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a) from `react-router-dom`,

```
import {Redirect} frpm 'react-router-dom'
```

And usage,

```
search(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.value){
        return <Redirect to={`/search/${this.state.value}`}
    }
}
```

Comment: Also no need to add condition in your render function.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I tried adding `<Redirect />` like you advised and it doesn't execute. Zero errors, nothing - it just doesn't work. I added `console.log()` before return to make sure `if` works - and it works. <Redirect />` just completely ignores me

Comment: Have you bind `this` to your `serach` function like, `this.search = this.search.bind(this)`, in constructor?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to add it in this post's snippet. Sorry for that

Comment: In search function try to print this.state.value

Comment: If nothing is working, then you can also try this "window.location.href= `/search/${this.state.value}`"

Comment: Thanks, it works. But since it is refreshing everything, I will use it as a temporary solution. I think the best option is to just move entire header to separate component and there everything should work as expected